# WPF and paypal integration

Tags: c#, wpf, paypal, integration

I'm asking this after being swamped by the amount of info etc on integrating my app and can't work out the best/appropriate solution. Paypal seem to have supplied several options.

We have a WPF app, which takes customer orders etc. We want to use PayPal to handle card payments and it needs to be PCI Compliant (Level A). What is the best/appropriate solution for this. The idea is to use a Browser control to pass through the amount/customer info and take the customers card details over the phone, so the only thing the business user needs to enter is the card info.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The answer (it seems) is the pay pal .net sdk,[link]http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-NET-SDK/ and that appears to do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

As i posted, this is the answer (it seems) is the pay pal .net sdk, [link](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-NET-SDK)